# How to get the previous Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs-api

I am trying to get google docs using apis. Every time I get 100 docs with one link used to get another 100 docs.How can I get the previos Docs using Google apis? I tried this,
tempfeed.getPreviousLink.getHref(); but it throws exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Docs API (like many other Google APIs) doesn't return a previous link.

I assume your code throws a null pointer exception because `getPreviousLink()` returns null.
If you need to navigate to previous pages you have to store the link to the current page before you move on with the next and build the navigation yourself.

Comment: Thanks Claudio for the quick response.And I have another question.Can we get the documents by using start-index parameter?

Comment: No, the Documents List API doesn't support that parameter for document listing.